# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException

Tags: groovy, enums

I am a newbie at groovy script. I am facing an unusual situation with the MissingPropertyException.

I have an enum in java defined as

```
public enum Fruits {
  a,b,c
}
```

my groovy script is as follows

```
import package.fruits.Fruits

println "fruit 1"+Fruits.a.toString()
println "fruit 2"+Fruits.b.toString()
```

In this script I can see that wherever I have referred to `Fruits.a.toString()` I am able to access it without any issues, but wherever I need to use `Fruit.b.toString()` I get a `MissingPropertyException`. Any ideas ?

edit:
this is the error I am facing

```
       groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: b for class: package.fruits.Fruits
```

Comment: I tried this myself with a java and groovy file.  It worked for me using Groovy 2.0.  What version of groovy are you using?  Also, are you running in an IDE?

Comment: @tim_yates I am pasting the exception above

Comment: Have you really called given one of your packages the name: `package` (which is a keyword)?